# Docker & gitlab-ci: Build application in Dockerfile but also create artifact

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a Dockerfile which builds my web application and then moves the built application to an nginx folder such that I only have to start the docker image locally and then access my application via localhost (I left out any details because for the moment I don't think they are necessary).

Now the problem is that I would also like to create an artifact in the gitlab-ci pipeline with the same Dockerfile. This artifact basically is the built application which is then processed later on.

How can I "copy" the application folder from inside the Dockerimage to the gitlab-ci environment?

Edit: I found

```
script:
    - docker container create --name dummy ${IMAGE}
    - docker cp dummy:/usr/share/nginx/html web
    - docker rm -f dummy
artifacts:
    paths:
        - web
```

to be a solution.

Comment: Well done, you can add it as an answer then ;)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My solution:

```
script:
    - docker container create --name dummy ${IMAGE}
    - docker cp dummy:/usr/share/nginx/html web
    - docker rm -f dummy
artifacts:
    paths:
        - web
```